# Add / Remove <li> item to list when Clicking a button - Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to create options for conditional rules in my project. I am trying to set up a smart filtering system (similar to email) where the user can choose different options in the dropdowns and that determines how the folder is populated dynamically.

I have seen many programs with this conditional functionality and I would like to re-create that in my Twitter Bootstrap project but I am unable to figure out how to get the Add(+) and Minus (-) functionality working on the frontend.

1. I am wondering if there is a plugin that already exists that does this type of functionality?
2. If not I am hoping to get some help to do this with JavaScript / jQuery implementation.

I have put the base HTML and CSS here so you can see what I am trying to do

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/y7CwE/1/

Note: By Default there is always 1 row (and that first row does not have a minus to remove it, only subsequent rows have the menus function)

```
<p>Please Create the following rules for your group</p>
<ul id="conditionRow-1">
<li>
    <select>
        <option>Client</option>
        <option>Resource</option>
        <option>Site</option>
        <option>Options</option>
        <option>Meals</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>is</option>
        <option>is not</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>X</option>
        <option>y</option>
        <option>Z</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</li>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Another Rule"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
</ul>

<ul id="conditionRow-2">
<li>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</li>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Another Rule"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove Rule"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Little amends` links should not be placed outside of `li`:

```
<p>Please Create the following rules for your group</p>
<ul>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>Client</option>
        <option>Resource</option>
        <option>Site</option>
        <option>Options</option>
        <option>Meals</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>is</option>
        <option>is not</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>X</option>
        <option>y</option>
        <option>Z</option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li> 
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Another Rule"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").tooltip();
    var add = true;
    $(document).on('click', '.icon-plus', function () {
        var $clone = $(this).closest('ul').clone();
        $clone.insertAfter($(this).closest('ul'));
        if(add==true){
            $clone.last('li').append('<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="remove this"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>');
            add=false;
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.icon-minus', function () {
       $(this).closest('ul').remove();
    });
});
```

### [checkout the updated 4th fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/y7CwE/4/)

Comment: great thanks - is there anyway though to keep the first row (i.e. not have the '-' icon to remove it?)

Comment: great thanks, but I just noticed that when I '+" add more rows (using the '+' icon from the newly created row) the '-' minus icons gets duplicated

Comment: thanks for help but now there is another problem.. When I add items and then remove list items and try add again the (-) icon does not appear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [jQuery's load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method for loading dynamic content instead of bunging it all in a string declaration (which is a nightmare to update):

```
$('.add').on('click', function() {
   var new_id = parseInt($('ul[id*=conditionRow').length) + 1;
   var selector = 'conditionRow-' + new_id;
   $(this).before('<ul id="' + selector + '"></ul>');
   $(selector).load('/path/to/load/script');
});

$('.remove').on('click', function() {
   if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      $(this).parents('ul').remove();
   }
});
```

In your load script, you simply output a HTML file:

```
<li>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</li>
<li>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
    </select>
</li>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add Another Rule"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove Rule"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
```

You can also pass parameters in your load call, to make your HTML a bit more dynamic.

Comment: Hi thanks, I am going to have backend help with the data, for now I was just looking for a FE implementation. cheers